# React Context API does not update state after async call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I was following [this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvM4hIxrqAw) for my own code but the state does not update after an async fetch call when clicking a button.

It is a real simple application, when the user loads the page, it loads also the state in `componentDidMount()`. When the user clicks the **Get "joke"** button, it set the state again with a new "joke".

When the page loads, the joke is well rendered after a couple of milliseconds. But when clicking the button it only shows the fetched "joke" in the console but the state is `null`.

When clicking the button I logged `this` object and it looks like this, is it correct?

[image]

Here is the code and the app "working": https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-shirley-qupr4

I appreciate any comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you forgot about binding action.
In JokeStat.js 
bind action in

```
        <JokesContext.Provider
                value={{
                    joke: this.state.joke,
                    getJoke: this.getJoke.bind(this)
                }}
            >
                {this.props.children}
            </JokesContext.Provider>
```

Or change

```
    async getJoke() {
        console.log("get joked triggered");
        const joke = await fetchJoke();
        console.log(joke,'joke')
        console.log("state", this.state);
        this.setState({ joke });
    }
```

to

```
     getJoke = async() => {
        console.log("get joked triggered");
        const joke = await fetchJoke();
        console.log(joke,'joke')
        console.log("state", this.state);
        this.setState({ joke });
    }
```

or 3rd option

```
     <JokesContext.Provider
         value={{
           joke: this.state.joke,
           getJoke: ()=>this.getJoke()
          }}
        >
           {this.props.children}
        </JokesContext.Provider>
```